# How do I change the backlight brightness on an iMac 12,2?

Tags: brightness, mac, apple, xrandr, backlight

Problem: I can't adjust the brightness of my iMac and it's killing me. (My eyes! The goggles do nothing!).

Has anyone gotten this to work?

-Booting with `rEFIt 0.14`

-Product Name: `iMac12,2`

-Kernel: `3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I've tried this fix: *https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/AppleGmuxBacklight*

But it doesn't seem to work since the kernel module doesn't seem to be loading. (`dmesg | grep gmux` returns nothing)

I've also tried doing this:

```
xrandr --output LVDS --brightness 0.3
```

and it dims the screen, but the mouse cursor still blazes away at full brightness.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

UPDATE:

Performing `ls /sys/class/backlight/` returns `acpi_video0`

-The brightness slider in "System Settings" has no effect.

-The "brightness" function keys on my apple bluetooth keyboard don't have any effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you `ls /sys/class/backlight/`

Comment: If I perform that, I get: `acpi_video0`
That's it.

Comment: You are not using external monitor, right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adjusting the `acpi_video0` with a terminal?

To check max value you can use run:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0
```

To check current brightness:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

To change brightness (input between 0 and your max_brightness):

```
echo YOUR_BRIGHTNESS_HERE | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

If this doesn't work perhaps your bootloader is messing something up or this video driver doesn't work on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Right,

I don't know if you tried this, but:

1. You could use the FN keys

or,

1. Just edit the brightness in System Settings!

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this gmux thing, but it looks like it is a `dynamic kernel module`.
Are you sure you didn't have any errors while installing it?

Remove the module:

```
sudo modprobe -r apple_gmux
```

Uninstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove apple-gmux-dkms --purge
```

Run update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Check your kernel version:

```
uname -a
```

e.g

> Linux MarsBox 3.5.0-26-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 8 23:18:20 UTC
>   2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Make sure the kernel headers are installed for your kernel

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-26-generic
```

Install the gmux again

```
sudo apt-get install apple-gmux-dkms
```

Enable module

```
sudo modprobe apple_gmux
```

Check if it works.